# basic getJSON question -- 2nd argument always seems to be ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'm very new to Javascript, Jquery and everything in between.  I've been trying to understand the `getJSON` function -- the documentation says that:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] )
```

- `url`: A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
- `data`: A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
- `success`: A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

A typical example:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });
```

Where is the 2nd argument in this `getJSON` call?

It seems like the `function(data)` is defining a function that gets called after the request succeeds, which implies that it should be the 3rd argument.

But it is passed as the second argument, directly after the `"ajax/test.json"` argument.

Does `getJSON` assume that if there are only 2 arguments, the second is the SUCCESS one?

Comment: The [ ] in the function signature of the documentation means that argument is optional. The function will use type checking to see if the second argument is a function or not, if it is it knows a data argument wasnt passed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `[]` in the documentation indicates that an argument is **optional**.

The `data` argument is omitted in your example. The second argument is, therefore, the `success` function.

The `getJSON` function tests the type of the second argument, determines it is a function, and uses it as the `success` function.

Comment: ok, I didn't realize the function did an implicit testing of the second argument.  thanks!

Comment: @slims _The `getJSON` function tests..._ -> [jquery/ajax (master): Line 845ff](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L845)

Answer (score 1):

This is how `getJSON` looks inside:

```
getJSON: function( url, data, callback ) {
    return jQuery.get( url, data, callback, "json" );
},
```

And here is how JQuery wraps `GET` and `POST` requests:

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( _i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {

        // Shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( typeof data === "function" ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        // The url can be an options object (which then must have .url)
        return jQuery.ajax( jQuery.extend( {
            url: url,
            type: method,
            dataType: type,
            data: data,
            success: callback
        }, jQuery.isPlainObject( url ) && url ) );
    };
} );
```

Examples above from [jquery sources](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) on github.